Correct pattern to add additional claims about the user once authenticated
I'm working on getting a better handle on ASP.NET Core authentication.
I have defined a simple user name/password authentication handler which is responsible for rebuilding the user's identity in HandleAuthentication, as well as signing in the user (creating the cookie) after sign-in is complete on the login page.
The login page, after doing user name password validation, will build the claims principal like this:
HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyAuthScheme", principal);

The line above will call my authentication handler's Signin method which persists a basic cookie with information from the principal object.
On the login page, the user has a checkbox option which offers the user also verify some key phrase (like 2fa).
If that checkbox is checked, the authenticated user is navigated to additional authentication screen where they will enter some key phrase they know.
Question:

Once the key phrase is confirmed, should it be added as a claim to existing user principal or a new identity shall be added? What's the right thing to do? I think it should be a claim?

We need to record this new fact that user has further verified (key phrase), So I'm calling HttpContext.SignIn method once more which rebuilds the cookie from the first login with additional claim.


It seems to work but I'm confused if I should have single auth handler or 1 handler each for user name, password and key phrase?
If I were two implement two different identities, shall they be stored in two different cookies?


Once the key phrase is confirmed, should it be added as a claim to existing user principal or a new identity shall be added? What's the right thing to do? I think it should be a claim?

In my opinion, you should firstly decide what claims you want to used inside your application.
For example, if inside your application you need to know how user login in, key phrase or username password, then you could add the claims inside the user. And there is no need to add multiple identities for key phrase and username password.

We need to record this new fact that user has further verified (key phrase), So I'm calling HttpContext.SignIn method once more which rebuilds the cookie from the first login with additional claim.

This is a bit confused, normally, the external login(two factor) and username password login is different method all allow user login.
I don't understand what you mean about allow user login twice. You could write the logic inside the normal login method which will check that checkbox , if click the click box then redirect to the external login page.
Inside the external login page, you could write the claims and use the httpcontext.signin to write the claims to the cookie. It will not call this login twice. Two login method will used for two kinds of login way.

Thank @Brando Zhang for the response.  "This is a bit confused, normally, the external login(two factor) and username password login is different method all allow user login."   --- When I say "Login" from the second page, I'm referring to the call of the signIn method.

OK, if this is your method, I suggest you put two login method, one is for the username password login another is two factor login.
